# Spring AOP execution - match method with specific parameter annotation and type

Tags: spring, expression, aop

Given the following method:

```
public void doSth(@AnnotationA @AnnotationB SomeType param) {
  ...do sth...
}
```

and @Aspect with the following @Around advice:

```
@Around("execution(* *(.., @com.a.b.AnnotationA (*), ..))")
```

Is there any possibility to modify the above expression to match a method with a parameter annotated with the `@AnnotationA` and with the `SomeType` type and to wildcard anything that would be between those two and before AnnotationA?

Something like `(* @com.a.b.AnnotationA * SomeType)` so the following methods would be matched:

```
doSth(@AnnotationA @AnnotationB SomeType param) 
doSth(@AnnotationB @AnnotationA SomeType param) 
doSth(@AnnotationA SomeType param)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). My answer is an exmple for how you should ask your questions in the future. I did your job this time, but I will not continue to do so in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers. Indeed much more better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class SomeType {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface AnnotationA {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface AnnotationB {}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    SomeType someType = new SomeType();
    application.one(11, someType, "x");
    application.two(someType, new Object());
    application.three(12.34D, someType);
    application.four(22, someType, "y");
    application.five(56.78D, someType);
  }

  // These should match
  public void one(int i, @AnnotationA @AnnotationB SomeType param, String s) {}
  public void two(@AnnotationB @AnnotationA SomeType param, Object o) {}
  public void three(double d, @AnnotationA SomeType param) {}

  // These should not match
  public void four(int i, @AnnotationB SomeType param, String s) {}
  public void five(double d, SomeType param) {}
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *(.., @de.scrum_master.app.AnnotationA (de.scrum_master.app.SomeType), ..))")
  public void intercept(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.one(int, SomeType, String))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.two(SomeType, Object))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.three(double, SomeType))
```